# How do I bring the tab with the ketchup error to the front?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, tabs

I'm using ketchup validation on a bootstrap user profile page.  there are multiple tabs.  when editing the secondary tabs and clicking save there can be ketchup errors on the primary tab.  however they aren't showing up because the secondary tab is being shown.

has anyone figured out how to bring the tab with the error to the front ?

thx

Comment: please post some code

Comment: when using tabs for forms should validate each stage before moving to next. Never heard of `ketchup` validation` but regardless of validation code used, is hard to make user friendly experience without doing each step individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap, you can bring a tab to 'the front' by adding a class of `.active` to it's parent `.tab-pane` element.

Comment: can someone post how to tweak ketchup to force adding that tab class?

Comment: related: ketchup doesn't seem to validate the second and third tabs on my form.  i like the post above, is there a way to invoke ketchup on the tab change action and have it apply to all the tabs?

Comment: the trick might be to modify ketchup to find the tab that had the error and bring it to the foreground.  this syntax works for bringing other tabs foreground:    $("a[href='#page_tab']").tab('show');